# How to record earlier video using OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I play a video A and i can write another video B from frame to frame now  ,
And now I want to trying to write earlier frames to my video !
For example :
When video A play to 10th sec , i press a key, and it start record from video A's 5th sec to video B ,
then when video A play to 15th sec , it stop record.
So video B's detail is video A's 5th to 15th sec.

Could you help me ?
I use VS C++ 2015, OpenCV3.2

It's my current code

```
while (1)
{
    if (startNewRecording == true)
    {
        startNewRecording = false;
        recording = true;
    }

    char c = (char)waitKey(fps);
    if (stop_run != 0)
    {
        if (!video.read(mat_frame))
            return -1;

        current_pos = (int)video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES); //get the frame pos now           

        if (c == 114) //r:start record
        {
            recording = !recording;
            if (recording == true)
                printf("Begin Recording\n");
            else
                printf("Recording Paused\n");
            //insert code here
            if (firstRun)
            {
                writer = VideoWriter(filename, fcc, fps, frameSize);
                if (!writer.isOpened())
                {
                    printf("ERROR OPENING FILE FOR WRITE\n");
                    getchar();
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (c == 115) //s:stop record
        {
            recording = false;
            printf("Stop Recording\n");
        }
        // Record From Earlier




        else
        {
            //setTrackbarPos("Second", "Video", current_pos / fps);
        }

        if (recording == true)
        {
            SYSTEMTIME sys;
            GetLocalTime(&sys);
            sprintf(systime, "%4d/%02d/%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d", sys.wYear, sys.wMonth, sys.wDay, sys.wHour, sys.wMinute, sys.wSecond);

            //writer.write(mat_frame); //只顯示
            putText(mat_frame, systime, Point(5, 40), 6, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            writer.write(mat_frame); //顯示也寫入
        }
        int h, h1, m, m1, s, s1;
        h = (current_pos / (int)fps) / 3600;
        m = (current_pos / (int)fps) % 3600 / 60;
        s = (current_pos / (int)fps) % 3600 % 60;
        h1 = video_totalsecond / 3600;
        m1 = video_totalsecond % 3600 / 60;
        s1 = video_totalsecond % 3600 % 60;

        sprintf(videotime, "%02d:%02d:%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s, h1, m1, s1);           
        putText(mat_frame, videotime, Point(5, 40), 2, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        //imwrite("Img000.jpg", mat_frame);
        imshow("Video", mat_frame);
        stop_run += 1;
    }

    if (c == 32) //空白鍵暫停
    {
        if (stop_run>0)
        {
            stop_run = -1;
            cout << "Pause" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            stop_run = 1;
            cout << "Play" << endl;
        }
    }
    if (c == 27)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Can you use frame rate and current frame number of video A to interpolate the first frame to record? Or you can just cache last 5 seconds of Video A in a `vector<Mat>`.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` to obtain the the time of the video, and to stop when this value reaches a difference of 10 secs?